# compare column of same files using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I want to print the third column till the sixth in the file if the first column is zero.

File:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0     X2   X3    X4   X5   X6
D1    D2   D3    D4   D5   D6 
Y1    Y2   Y3    Y4   Y5   Y6
0     A2   A3    A4   A5   A6
```

I tried this code:

```
awk '$1==0{key=$0;if(prev!=key){print saved};prev=key;saved=$0}END{print saved}'
```

and the resulting output is:

```
0     X2   X3    X4   X5   X6
0     A2   A3    A4   A5   A6
```

but my expecting output is this:

```
X3    X4   X5   X6
A3    A4   A5   A6
```

Comment: So you want to print the lines having first column == 0? If so, `awk '$1==0 {$1=$2=""; print $0}' file` would make it.

Comment: i don't want to print whole line, i need from col3 to 6 having first column ==0

Comment: That's what my solution does, @sara

Comment: @ fedorqui, i am getting error on using awk '$1==0 {$1=$2=""; print $0}' file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk '$1==0{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' OFS='\t' file
X3      X4      X5      X6
A3      A4      A5      A6
```

A scalable solution that prints from the third column until the last:

```
$ awk '$1==0{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s",$i(i==NF?ORS:OFS)}' OFS='\t' file
X3      X4      X5      X6
A3      A4      A5      A6
```

A parametized version if you don't necessarily want to print until the last column  *(n=5)*:

```
$ awk '$1==0{for(i=3;i<=n;i++)printf "%s",$i(i==n?ORS:OFS)}' OFS='\t' n=5 file
X3      X4      X5
A3      A4      A5
```

Comment: @ sudo_O , awk '$1==0{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' OFS='\t' file worked well; Thanks you